# 403 forbidden on accessing API gateway url from APP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am trying to access the API gateway URL from the frontend app using Faraday gem side but every time I am getting 403 Forbidden.

The URL looks like below:

```
https://4ep34te755.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/healthe-us124/clients/{clientId}/members
```

I looked online about it and I am trying the correct URL. I get successful response from postman for the same URL and I have `API Key Required: false` on API gateway.
my cloudformation stack is on STAGE(`healthe-us124`). There is a separate stack for for STAGE(healthe-stage). I tried stage and prod URLS as well but same error.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: By saying `app side`, do you mean backend that is behind the API gateway? Like a lambda function attached to to some gateway endpoing? Asking because app can easily be a frontent app, consuming the api from the same side as the postman.

Comment: yes Frontend APP which is using Faraday gem

Comment: Isn't this a CORS error?

Comment: Is the app service running inside a VPC, with a VPC endpoint for execute-api?